# Как я могу получить данные после отправки запроса с aiohttp ClientSession в json

Tags: python, json, aiohttp

Есть код:

```
url = 'https://goo.su/api/convert'

params = {
    'token': 'my_token',
    'url': vk_url
}

async with ClientSession() as session:
    async with session.get(url, params=params) as response:
        response = await response.text()
```

Ответ с сайта:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*Мне необходимо получить короткую ссылку*

Comment: Если сервер отдает json, то берите не `response.text()`, а `response.json()`, тогда результатом будет словарь. Из этого словаря уже по нужным ключам получаете данные, например `response.json()['short_url']`, только предварительно проверяйте, что по ключу `'success'` лежит `True`.

Comment: Спасибо, вы указали мне в каком направлении необходимо двигаться, чтобы получить желаемый результат.